# How to let the domain ip point to a web2py app instead of the default "welcome" app

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, web2py

I want to enter my app by *http://my.domain.ip/*  instead of *http://my.domain.ip/myapp*.should I change the apache config(conf.d/deault.conf) or do something else?
   I want to bind some domain names to other apps in web2py/applications if this domain ip test success.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443


<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=apache group=apache processes=1 threads=1
  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/web-apps/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  <Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>
```

I tried to set `<Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications>` to `<Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/app>`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web2py's [parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Parameter-based-system) allows you to map domains to apps. In routes.py:

```
routers = dict(
  BASE  = dict(
      domains = {
          'domain1.com' : 'app1',
          'domain2.com' : 'app2',
      }
  ),
)
```

The [pattern-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Pattern-based-system) could be used as well.

Comment: Thanks,that's what I want.